# Linux Real Mode Interface in a linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I have a BIOS function I need to call from time to time on an embedded system, and using LRMI I was able to call it successfully from a user space program. Now I want to do the same from a loadable kernel module.

Is there any way to do this? Some other library maybe?

Comment: Embedded system uses BIOS? What kind of embedded system?

Comment: If it's an embedded system, you should find a work-around. Perhaps you should explain WHY you want to call the BIOS from linux? For example, if you're trying to reflash the BIOS, then perhaps you could boot into a DOS partition to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the mode the Processor is in (which is protected mode, which turns on after bios initializes all of the resources).  In order to use BIOS interrupts again, you will have to use v8086 mode, which is when the processor emulates a 16bit real mode machine.  You can then set your registers and call your interrupt with a virtual mode program.

Here's how to get into virtual mode: http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev23.html

You could also try and switching into Real mode, but this involves resetting the processor.  I don't know how you would do this programmatically, since you probably can't.

Comment: Actually, LRMI is probably putting the CPU in the v8086 state automatically in order to reach the BIOS calls.  If you want to do this manually, some quick research should help you figure it out, even though apparently its a b'eotch.